# IS MySQL logical operator XOR equivalent OR with negation

Tags: mysql, performance, logical-operators

Is there a difference in results and performance between those queries ?

```
SELECT a.id FROM table a WHERE (C1 = 'value' XOR C2 = 'value');

SELECT a.id FROM table a WHERE (C1 != 'value' OR C2 !='value');
```

Comment: if `C1 <> 'value' and  $C2 <> 'value'`

`(C1 = 'value' XOR C2 = 'value') => false`
`(C1 != 'value' OR C2 !='value') =>  true`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you could test this yourself and find out.

Answer (score 3):

`XOR` is not equivalent to `OR` with negation.  `XOR` is equivalent to the following logic:

```
WHERE ((c1 = 'value' AND c2 <> 'value') OR
       (c1 <> 'value' AND c2 = 'value') 
      )
```

Interestingly, your second expression is the same as:

```
WHERE NOT (c1 = 'value' AND c2 = 'value')
```

I think you should review boolean logic and truth tables.

Comment: FWIW: Wrong equivalence. `a xor b` is equivalent to `(a and not b) or (not a and b)`. OR how it is often said in a human language: "a or b but not both": `(a or b) and not (a and b)`. Or add to your formulation the missing "not": `not ((a and b) or (not a and not b))`.

Comment: ah ha. Maybe you meant the algebraic expression sometimes used when building an XOR circuit - but you mixed up AND and OR:  `(a or b) and (not a or not b)`. However, that isn't a formula that people easily grasp.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve . . . You are of course correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement says that either `C1` OR `C2`, but *not* both should be equal to `'value'`. The second says that at least one of `C1`, `C2` must *not* be equal to `'value'`.

So if `C1 != 'value'` and `C2 != 'value'`, the first expression will be `false` while the second will evaluate to `true`. It means that in general, the results will differ.

Since an `XOR` operation is not more expensive than an `OR` operation, I don't think there will be any significant differences in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Some other answers point out that the two expressions can yield different results.  As for performance...

I am pretty sure both of those will do full scans, regardless of what indexes you have.  You can find out by doing `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;` I would expect the output for either to be something like:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | canada | ALL  | province,ppc  | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 5484 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Conceptual Dissection:**

*Understand OR >>*

`Literal meaning`: Evaluate one or both conditions to conclude result

`TimeComplexity (Performance)`: If first condition check is false, then only processing engine will evaluate second condition to conclude result.

NOTE: n = 2 here:

O(n) (Upper Bound) 

Ω(1) (Lower Bound)

*Understand XOR*

`Literal meaning`: Always evaluate both conditions to conclude result. Both can't be true at same time. `(A XOR B)` means: `(A AND !B) OR (!A AND B)`
`TimeComplexity (Performance)`: Check both conditions and compare result using NOT & AND operator.

NOTE: n = 2 here, +2 to apply NOT and then AND logical operator :

O(2n+2) (Upper Bound) 

Ω(n+2) (Lower Bound)

As you can see the processing engine has to perform more steps to derive result for XOR. Conceptually, XOR will always be slower than OR.

**PS** I am sure all processing engine's internals are highly optimized to handle logical operations very well. So, the difference won't even be noticeable unless we are talking about millions of transactions. And performance shouldn't even be question here, because its not apple to apple comparison. Both OR & XOR logical operators serve different purpose. Its same like comparing to any other operator, lets say between OR & AND, which will not make sense.